# Firebase Fetching Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can fetch data from firebase console. But how to get node from the database.

[image]

Please refer to below code :

```
let current_uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        self.userRef?.queryOrdered(byChild: "Email").observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded) { (snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let email = value?["Email"] as? String
            let password = value?["Password"] as? String
            print("User Email \(email!) and User Password \(password!)")
        }
```

But i am bit confuse how to get `4dS6fdWy4of8VyDN8eouwqIk38j2` remember i have to fetch all the users from the database.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you mean `snapshot.key` ?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 yes you're right... thanks